# How can I see the list of all open folders in the finder in the Open/Save dialog?

Tags: finder

Commonly, in the Open/Save dialog I would like to get the list of all the folders that are open in the finder (as these are the ones that I'm using at the moment). I tried to define a smart folder with the list of recent folders, but this doesn't do the trick. Is there a way to introduce this list in these dialogs ?

Answer (score 1):

With any Finder window open, press the key combination <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to merge all open Finder windows into one Finder window.

Additionally, here’s an example of a Smart Folder one could implement:

[image]